# Navigating localhost:4200 to a 404 page

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router

We are wanting to have the root `localhost:4200` (or the deployed root URL, like `myApp.com`) navigate to a 404. The app is designed to only have `/home/id/anotherID` because the `id` and `anotherID` are to be used in the backend. I've tried both `{path: '',ccomponent: ErrorPageComponent}` and 
  `{path: '**',component: ErrorPageComponent},`. I can not seem to get the root url to go to a 404 page. Currently we have the following for our Routing:

```
  {
    path: 'home/:rmId/:leadId',
    canActivate: [SSOAuthGuard],
    component: ScreenComponent,
  },

  {
    path: '',
    component: ErrorPageComponent
  },

  {
    path: '**',
    component: ErrorPageComponent

  },
```

Thanks

Comment: try the second one like this: `{ path: '', component: ErrorPageComponent, pathMatch: 'full' },`

Comment: Try removing the `{ path: '', component: ErrorPageComponent }` line. I've just created a new app and it's working as expected with only `{ path: '', component: ErrorPageComponent }`

Comment: I'm a little confused on this one, you removed `{ path: '', component: ErrorPageComponent }` and then got it to work by adding it back in?

Comment: you are right, I'm sorry.  I deleted the `{ path: '**', component: ErrorPageComponent }` line. Thanks for spotting that!

Answer (score 0):

To target only the root url, you should use `pathMatch='full'`.
Have you tried that?

Comment: Yes,`localhost:4200` does not go to the 404 page.

Comment: hum, any errors in the console? Are you declaring the component?

Comment: `localhost:4200/<garbage String>` will work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try
`{path: '**', component: NotfoundComponent, pathMatch: 'prefix'},`

Also, have this as your last entry. Be sure that the project compiles and the routes are working.

Comment: Tried `  {
    path: '**',
    component: ErrorPageComponent,
    pathMatch: 'prefix'
  },` as my last entry. App worked, no console errors. Still goes to  ScreenComponent.

Comment: then some guesses: - Are you sure your not found components OnInit or Consctructor does not redirect back to ScreenComponent? Are the routes used by the app fully copied to your question? Are you sure your app is updated to the new routes? (in the console where you run ng serve, no error message can be seen?) What happens if you restart your app? What happens if you check the current [activated route](https://angular.io/api/router/ActivatedRoute) in your Screencomponent on init? Can you provide a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/) reproduction of your problem maybe?